# IIS/ASP.NET error - malformed XML element

Tags: css, asp.net, xml, iis

I try to run ASP.NET webshop on my computer.
I have to change default layout of my shop (shop is now online and I want to do changes offline to not get angry my customers:P).

After I download shop from FTP account I put all files to IIS folder and then i got error message like this:

```
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img841/9567/leh9b.jpg
```

the error code is: 0x8007000d -> Microsoft support page says:
"Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config file or from the Web.config file."

But I realy don't know what i should delete:(

I realy don't need all functions of shop I just have to change CSS styles and homepage layout. So i need to see how shop looks like. Any sugestions?

Comment: run your web.config thru a xml validator.

Comment: validator says: no errors was found